# Does "allows to + verb" imply that the corresponding event occured?

Tags: meaning, phrases, verbs

Example:

> Yahoo vulnerability allows hacker to delete 1.5 million records from database.

Does this imply that the hacker *did* delete those records or just that he was *in the position to* delete the records but not necessarily performed the action?

Comment: First, notice this is a headline. There are different rules for headlines. Second, yes, it does imply that; that's one of the different rules. Warning: Don't talk like a headline; people won't understand you.

Comment: @JohnLawler This is a real-world headline. I'm just discussing its meaning. I wouldn't use it in my communication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The headline implies that the records were deleted because "allows" is its verb. If the headline were "Yahoo! Vulnerability Discovered Which Allows Hackers to Delete 1.5 Million Records From Database" it would not imply this, because it is not performing the action (it is being discovered rather than allowing access).

EDIT: I should note that another reason the headline implies the records were deleted is that it says the vulnerability allowed *a* hacker to delete *1.5 million* records. By specifying one hacker out from the collective of hackers, it implies that he is in some way distinguished from the rest, in this case because he (may have) deleted Yahoo's records. Unless Yahoo only **has** 1.5 million records, those are also distinguished from the others by virtue of their being deleted.

Comment: Yea, makes sense.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for discussing this topic over here. 
I appreciate the person who edited the previous answer. My points for giving the title as this are:

1. Hacker didn't delete the database.
2. The vulnerability allowed the hacker to delete the database; this doesn't mean **deleted**.
3. 1.5 million records are related to a specific sub-domain of Yahoo! i.e. suggestions.yahoo.com
4. Focusing on a particular hacker is purely intentional, because he is the one who has discovered the vulnerability, and reported to Yahoo! and has been patched prior to public release.

I HOPE THAT YOUR DOUBT MIGHT GET RESOLVED. IF STILL HAVE ANY DOUBT PLEASE TWEET ME

Comment: Notice that this is a StackExchange site about the **English language**. The OP was asking about what the phrasing of that headline _implied_ as used in the English language; he did not ask what actually happened.

Comment: Second, StackExchange sites are not the same as forums; they are focused at _questions and answers_, not discussions. You may benefit by taking a look at this page: http://english.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: @IQAndreas That's my fault, sorry. I told him that we were "discussing his headline" here.